# how to use JsFiddle to demonstrate ajax using php?

Tags: php, ajax, jsfiddle

Can someone tell me how to use jsfiddle to demonstrate ajax using php ?
As it is done in this

```
$.ajax({
        url:'myAjax.php',
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(data, response);
            $('#output').html(response);
        },
        error: function () {
            $('#output').html('Bummer: there was an error!');
        },
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/amrata/j42t5y30/ file ?
How to pass external php file ? Path ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a absolute url

```
url:'http://path_to_my_site.ro/myAjax.php',
```

disable cors or whitelist jsfiddle on your server